# Windows Embedded Compact 7 - device requirements?

Tags: embedded, windows-embedded

I can't find anywhere what are the hardware requirements of embedded device to successfully  run Windows Embedded Compact 7? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll agree it is hard to find the hardware requirements, but what I have found out is that the minimum footprint is ~300 MB for windows compact 7 compared to 40 MB of XPe

Comment: Read the following for a reasonably comprehensive list of features and requirements - if you can read between the lines, http://www.windowsfordevices.com/c/a/Windows-For-Devices-Articles/Comparison-between-Windows-Embedded-Standard-2009-and-Windows-Embedded-Standard-2011/